# PostgreSQL - I want to query out the latest Subscription status for every client with the date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

The client can opt-in or opt-out for subscription from time to time. I need the latest Status of every client with the subscription date.

If the client has opted-in at the first instance and never opted-out again, I need the first date when they opted-in. However, if the same client has opted-out after opting-in and then opted-in again, I need to know the date corresponding to the latest opt-in.
(FIRST YES or FIRST YES after NO).

Can anyone guide how to query this in Postgresql.
[image]

For example, for Client C

[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Most people here want sample table date _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I'm attempting it in MYSQL, but I need it in Postgresql. Currently, I'm writing diff queries to solve this. nothing concrete.

Comment: Can you provide the desired output?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY SubscriptionDate DESC) as Rn
FROM Table_name
WHERE SubscriptionStatus = 'Y'
)
SELECT ClientID, Source, 
SubscriptionStatus, SubscriptionDate
FROM CTE1
WHERE Rn = 1;
```

Comment: Awesome. Almost solved my problem. I can make the final changes. thanks Nishant